# How can I make bootstrap multiselect optgroups collapse by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using [bootstrap's multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableCollapsibleOptGroups) with `enableCollapsibleOptGroups` set to true.

What I have now:

[image]

I want to have optgroups collapsed by default:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David's answer didn't work for me. But these two solutions worked:

**Solution 1:**

```
buttonContainer: '<div id="example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container" />',
onDropdownShown: function() {
                $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container .caret-container').click();
            },
onDropdownHidden: function() {
                $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container .caret-container').click();
            }
```

**Solution 2:**

```
buttonContainer: '<div id="example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container" />'
```

Then:

```
setTimeout( function(){ 
    $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container .caret-container').click();
}  , 2000 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a simple example for this here: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableCollapsibleOptGroups.

The trick is triggering the click event for each group once after loading the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed').multiselect({
            enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
            buttonContainer: '<div id="example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container" />'
        });
        $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container .caret-container').click();
    });
</script>
<select id="example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option value="1-1" disabled>Option 1.1</option>
        <option value="1-2" selected="selected">Option 1.2</option>
        <option value="1-3" selected="selected">Option 1.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
        <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
        <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I had to do it on onDropdownShown/onDropdownHidden. One other solution was to do it after 2 seconds like:

setTimeout( function(){ 
            $('#example-enableCollapsibleOptGroups-collapsed-container .caret-container').click();
  }  , 2000 );

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Did you check the example provided in the documentation (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableCollapsibleOptGroups)? Key to this example is the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` as the page needs to load first.

Comment: I know. I already have it inside the ready function but it still didn't work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. Will have a closer look on the example. Let me know if you stumble across the problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've came up with different solution that works well for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="multiselect-filter-dropdown-wrapper">
  <label id="multiselect-filter-dropdown-label">Filter:</label>

  <select multiple id="multiselect-filter-dropdown"></select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#multiselect-filter-dropdown').multiselect({
  enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true
}); //init with required options

$('#multiselect-filter-dropdown').multiselect('dataprovider', multiselectFilterDataProvider); //populate with required data

$('#multiselect-filter-dropdown-wrapper ul.multiselect-container li:not(.multiselect-all):not(.multiselect-group)')
.hide()
.addClass('multiselect-collapsible-hidden'); //collapse required opt groups
```

Comment: This is the best solution as triggering click event takes time if there are many options.

Answer (score 1):

After long try, it works to me.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<select id="products" multiple="multiple">
                    <optgroup class="test" label="Group 1" >
                        <option value="Option 1.1">Option 1.1</option>
                        <option value="Option 1.2">Option 1.2</option>
                        <option value="Option 1.3">Option 1.3</option>
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label="Group 2">
                        <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
                        <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
                        <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
                    </optgroup>

</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#products').multiselect({
                enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
                collapseOptGroupsByDefault: true
            });
        });
</script>

<style>
li.multiselect-item.multiselect-group input[type="checkbox"]{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]